# How to create subscription of multiple plans in Recurly by one transaction?

Tags: recurly

I have list of plans.I want to allow to select more than one plan to user.I am not able to find the option to allow them to select more than one plan subscriptions using one transaction only.

Answer (score 5):

Individual subscriptions are always billed separately. You may want to consider creating a $0 plan, and then having each plan as an add-on. That way a customer can select multiple items and have them all billed together, on the same invoice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But cannot hide the $0 amount on UI. and how can we make add-ons mandatory in this case ?

Comment: Your best bet would be to use Recurly.js to collect *just* the billing information, then use the API to submit the subscription information. That way your checkout page can look however you'd like, while still securely handling the CC data.